# Pipeline in bitbucket failed by composer error

Tags: linux, composer-php, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I try pipeline in bitbucket. This is default conf which I am using:

```
# This is a sample build configuration for PHP.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/e8YWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: php:5.6.36
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      caches:
        - composer
      script:
        - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
        - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
        - composer install
        - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I am getting this error

```
+ composer install
  Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/rootfor details
  Composer could not find a composer.json file in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
  To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Even when I created composer.json (all path as well) in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build.

Btw, why tool looking for composer in such path? I have installed composer on /home/username/.composer

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please rephrase the post. Why tool is doing what? What have you installed in /home/username/.composer? Why don't you use [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/) with composer installed? Why don't you create composer.json in that path before running composer install and see if the error persists?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I fill there some words.

Comment: I installed composer manually and it works. When I will write composer to terminal it does everything what have to do. In path /home/username/.composer is composer.json. I do not know why bitbucket do not use that composer and try out looking for composer.json in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build. There is not composer, I created that file by hand, but it did not help.

Comment: Have you installed composer on your PC? Do you know that bitbucked pipelines are executed in docker environment?

Answer (score 1):

Use another docker container for deployment instead of `image: php:5.6.36`.
There is an official composer container: https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/
It's based on `php:7-alpine3.7`, I hope PHP7 does the job with your application too.